# Changing the value of attributes using QgsFeature in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, fields-attributes, features

The script doesn't work as if I wanted.

Script:

```
mylayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Kuniarka")[0]

dane = 'a'
for seg in mylayer.getFeatures():
    #seg = next (mylayer.getFeatures())
    seg["WSP_X"] = dane
    mylayer.updateFeature(seg)
```

Effect:
[image]

Desired effect:
[image]

Script improvisation:

```
mylayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Kuniarka")[0]

dane = ["a", "b"]
for seg in mylayer.getFeatures():
    #seg = next (mylayer.getFeatures())
    seg["WSP_X"] = dane
    mylayer.updateFeature(seg)
```

Script improvisation2:

```
mylayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Kuniarka")[0]

for feat in mylayer.getFeatures():
    dane = ["a", "b"]
    mylayer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(), 3, dane)
```

Script doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427212/changing-the-value-of-attributes-using-geocoding-in-pyqgis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking to access the list index.

```
dane = ['a', 'b']
print(dane[0]) #prints 'a'
```

In your code this would give (there are better ways in python to loop over 2 iterators):

```
from qgis.core import *
mylayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("point1")[0]

dane = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
i = 0
with edit(mylayer):
    for seg in mylayer.getFeatures():
        #seg = next (mylayer.getFeatures())
        print(seg.id())
        seg['name'] = dane[i]
        i += 1
        mylayer.updateFeature(seg)
```