# Geocoding address in attribute table with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, geocoding, features

The script doesn't work as if I wanted.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from .resources import *
import json

mylayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layer")[0]
features = mylayer.getFeatures()
for f in features:  
 dane1 = f.attribute(2)
        
url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&&format=json&limit=1&q='+dane1

response = requests.get(url)
    
aaa = json.dumps(response.json()[0]["lat"], ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
bbb = json.dumps(response.json()[0]["lon"], ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

material = aaa.replace('"','') + ', ' + bbb.replace('"','')
                   
mylayer.startEditing()

forum = [material]
i = 0

for seg in mylayer.getFeatures():
    seg['WSP_X'] = forum[i]
    i += 1
    mylayer.updateFeature(seg)
    mylayer.commitChanges()
```

Effect:

[image]

Desired effect:

[image]

Script doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue is that you are making the Nominatim request only once. It does not get updated and re-sent for each feature. There are a couple of other issues too, see my comments in the code for explanation.

```py
from qgis.core import *
from .resources import *
import requests
import json

mylayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("layer")[0]
features = mylayer.getFeatures()

# open the edit session outside the loop
mylayer.startEditing()

for f in features:  
    dane1 = f.attribute(2)
    
    # move the URL formulation and Nominatim request inside the loop to ensure the URL is upated with each new address
    url = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/?addressdetails=1&&format=json&limit=1&q='+dane1

    # send request once for every feature
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    aaa = json.dumps(response.json()[0]["lat"], ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
    bbb = json.dumps(response.json()[0]["lon"], ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

    material = aaa.replace('"','') + ', ' + bbb.replace('"','')

    # remove the `forum` variable and work directly with the `material` variable
    #forum = [material]
    
    # no need to get the features again because you are already iterating through them
    
    # corrected the field name and use the `f` variable from the original feature iterator, rather than `seg`
    f['WSP_X_Y'] = material
    mylayer.updateFeature(f)

mylayer.commitChanges()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Once I was inspired by [@ThomasG77's idea](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/395415/99589), so now I am suggesting another approach using the QGIS's domestic class [`QgsNominatimGeocoder`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsNominatimGeocoder.html) with [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/) geocoder under the hood. It is an open-source solution, otherwise one can use the [`QgsGoogleMapsGeocoder`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGoogleMapsGeocoder.html) class, where an [`apiKey`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsGoogleMapsGeocoder.html#qgis.core.QgsGoogleMapsGeocoder.apiKey) must be specified.

I see *several advantages* over [a nice solution from @Matt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/427213/99589): (1) no need to install/use not built-in Python packages e.g. [`requests`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (however, it is included in QGIS) (2) no need to deal with proxies and certificates, in `requests` package it is usually needed by setting `verify` and `proxies` parameters (3) no need *"to play"* with the url. Perhaps there is *one disadvantage*: this solution is only suitable for QGIS 3.18 and later versions.

Let's assume there is a point layer called *'random_points_test'* with its attribute table, see image below.

[image: input]

Proceed with `Plugins > Python Console > Show Editor` ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#scripting-in-the-python-console)) and paste the script below

```py
# imports
from statistics import mean
from qgis.core import (
    QgsNominatimGeocoder,
    QgsGeocoderContext,
    QgsCoordinateTransformContext,
    )


def geoms_to_coords(geoms: list) -> str:
    """
    Convert a list with geometries into a string with a single coordinates pair.
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param geoms: a list with geometries of 'QgsGeometry: Point (X Y)' type
    Returns:
    ==========
    :return: a string with YX-coordinates
    """
    # convert a list with geometries into a list with sets of x,y coordinates
    geoms_coordinates = [(geom.asPoint().x(), geom.asPoint().y()) for geom in geoms]

    # get a mean value of all x and y inside a set
    x_avg, y_avg = [mean(coords) for coords in zip(*geoms_coordinates)]

    # represent mean x and y as a string with 6 digits after comma
    coords = f"{format(y_avg, '.6f')}, {format(x_avg, '.6f')}"

    return coords


def geocoding_the_address(address: str, country: str) -> str:
    """
    Geocode an address into coordinates with Nominatim Geocoder.
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param address: an address to geocode
    :param country: a code of a country
    Returns:
    ==========
    :return: a string with coordinates or 'No result'
    """
    # call the Nominatim Geocoder with a country code parameter
    geocoder = QgsNominatimGeocoder(countryCodes=country)
    # call the context to encapsulate the context of a geocoding operation
    context = QgsGeocoderContext(QgsCoordinateTransformContext())
    # set a method for geocoding a string with an address
    output = geocoder.geocodeString(address, context)

    # check if the output of geocoding is not empty,
    # otherwise output 'No result'
    if len(output):
        # a list with geometries of each valid output
        output_geoms = [out.geometry() for out in output if out.isValid()]
        # achieve a single coordinate pair
        output_coords = geoms_to_coords(output_geoms)

        return output_coords

    else:
        return "No result"


def address_to_coords(
    layer_name: str, input_field: str, output_field: str, country: str = None
):
    """
    Geocode a field with an address into a field string with coordinates of the address.
    Parameters:
    ==========
    :param layer_name: the name of a layer
    :param input_field: the input field with an address
    :param output_field: the output field for coordinates
    :param (optional) country: to restrict results to one or more countries.
        It must be in ISO 3166-1alpha2 code and comma-separated.
    """

    # get layer by name
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]

    # get all fields of the layer
    fields = layer.fields()
    # get names of all fields of the layer
    fields_names = layer.fields().names()

    # check if the input field is in all fields of the layer
    if input_field in fields_names:

        # get index of the input field
        idx_in = fields.indexFromName(input_field)

        layer.startEditing()

        # check if the output field already exists,
        # otherwise create it (of a string type)
        if not output_field in fields_names:
            new_field = QgsField(output_field, QVariant.String)
            layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([new_field])
            layer.updateFields()

        for feature in layer.getFeatures():
            # get address value of the input field for each feature
            address = feature.attribute(idx_in)

            # check if the address value exists
            if address:
                # appropriate the output field with a new value
                feature[output_field] = geocoding_the_address(address, country)

            else:
                # appropriate the output field with 'No result'
                feature[output_field] = "No result"

            layer.updateFeature(feature)

    layer.commitChanges()
    print('Done!')


# executing the function
address_to_coords('random_points_test', "address", "WSP_X_Y", 'pl')
```

In the code above, please do not forget to apply several changes in the last line: `address_to_coords('random_points_test', "address", "WSP_X_Y", 'pl')` before running it.

Press `Run script` [image: run script] and get the output that will look like:

[image: result]

---

**References:**

- [Geocoding address involving non-ASCII characters in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250385/geocoding-address-involving-non-ascii-characters-in-pyqgis)
- [PyQGIS 101: Creating & editing a new vector layer](https://anitagraser.com/pyqgis-101-introduction-to-qgis-python-programming-for-non-programmers/pyqgis101-creating-editing-a-new-vector-layer/)